# Warning message using robust regression with lmRob: Denominator smaller than tl= 1e-100 in test for bias

Tags: r

I'm doing robust regressions in R using `lmRob` from the `robust` package. I have four response variables (R1-R4) and eight predictors (X1-X8), thus doing four separate robust regressions à la:

```
`library(robust)
mod.rob <- lmRob(R1 ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5 + X6 + X7 + X8, data=dataset)
summary(mod.rob)`
```

... and so on for the four response variables.

R1 to R3 works perfect, but when I try to do R4 I get two error messages. First:

`Warning message:
In lmRob.fit.compute(x, y, x1.idx = x1.idx, nrep = nrep, robust.control = robust.control,  :
  Max iteration for refinement reached.`

... and after `summary(mod.rob)`:

```
`Warning messages:
1: In test.lmRob(object) :
  Denominator smaller than tl= 1e-100  in test for bias.
2: In test.lmRob(object) :
  Denominator smaller than tl= 1e-100  in test for bias.`
```

In the resulting model all t-values and estimates are zero and all p-values are 1, except for the intercept. The test for bias M-estimate has NaN for both statistic and p-value, which I suspect is where the model fails for some reason. If i change the parameter `mxr` to 200 I get rid of the first warning, but not the second ones.

I have tried to modify some other parameters; `initial.alg, tl, tlo, tua`, but to no avail. Doing an ordinary LS with `mod.lm <- lm(R4 ~ X1 ... X8)` works just fine. I guess my statistics knowledge is lacking here, because I don't really understand what is wrong.

Edit:

I have uploaded the data here: http://jmp.sh/QVV6O9w

My goal is to fit regression models using these data. My statistics background is a lot more lacking than I thought, so when diving deeper into regression modelling I found it a bit more complicated than I first had hoped. In short, I just want to construct models that are as accurate as possible. The predictors are all based on previous literature, and from what I have read, it is more justified to keep them all in the model rather than using some stepwise method. I have so far tried to learn various kinds of robust techniques, GAMs, and bootstrapping, since the OLS linear models violate the normality of residuals assumption. I am at a loss of how to proceed, really.

Comment: Can you share the data?

Comment: Have you tried fitting a model with less explanatory variables?

Comment: Thank you for you replies. I have uploaded the data here: http://jmp.sh/QVV6O9w